# Entity Framework Code First (New Database) Producing Error - "CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'."

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have created a new project (ASP.NET MVC) that will use Entity Framework Code First to create a new Database and add records to the database one time only and populate a drop down.
I am trying to figure out how to generate the database automatically.  So far, when I run the code I get "CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.".  Master is not the correct database.  What would I need to modify in my code or connection string to create the database automatically from scratch?

Controller:

```
namespace TDReport.Controllers
{
    public class ReportController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Report/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var db = new StageContext();
            if (!db.Database.Exists())
            {
                db.Database.Create();
                db.Stages.Add(new Stage { PCR = 201 });
                db.Stages.Add(new Stage { PCR = 202 });
                db.Stages.Add(new Stage { PCR = 203 });
                db.Stages.Add(new Stage { PCR = 501 });
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Context Class:

```
namespace TDReport.Models
{
    public class StageContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Stage> Stages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Report> Reports {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Model:

```
namespace TDReport.Models
{
    public class Stage
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int PCR { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Connection String Tags:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-TDReport-20140825134744;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-TDReport-20140825134744.mdf" />
    <add name="StageProductionEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\StageProduction.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a connection string that matches the name of db context if you have parameterless constructor in the db context.

> `<add name="StageContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
>   connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial
>   Catalog=TheDatabaseName;Integrated
>   Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\TheDatabaseName.mdf" />`

Comment: Thank you very much.  This change is now making the database create automatically.